# Como faço a multiplicação de um array dentro de uma função em JS?

Tags: javascript, array, funções

A pergunta e basicamente essa: 
Necessitamos uma função produto que receba um array de números e retorne o produto: o resultado de multiplicar todos os elementos entre si.

Por exemplo, produto([1, 4, 7]) deve retornar 28, que é 1 * 4 * 7.

Answer (score 6):

Você pode usar o [`rest operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) para isso:

```js
function mult(...terms) {
  let current = 1
  for (const term of terms) current *= term
  
  return current
}

console.log(mult(1, 4, 7))
```

Se você quiser usar um `array` no primeiro parâmetro, basta trocar `...terms` por `terms`:

```js
function mult(terms) {
  let current = 1
  for (const term of terms) current *= term
      
  return current
}

console.log(mult([1, 4, 7]))
```

Answer (score 5):

O `array` possui uma função `reduce` que retorna um único valor de acordo com os elementos existentes.

> [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
>
> O método `reduce()` executa uma função `reducer` (provida por você) para cada membro do array, resultando num único valor de retorno.
>
> **Exemplo:**
>
> ```js
> const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
> const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;
>
> // 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
> console.log(array1.reduce(reducer));
> // expected output: 10
>
> // 5 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
> console.log(array1.reduce(reducer, 5));
> // expected output: 15
> ```

Aplicando no seu problema:

```js
const multiplicar = (itens) => itens.reduce((acumulador, item) => acumulador * item);

console.log(multiplicar([1, 4, 7]));
```

Answer (score 2):

Pode usar o `for` clássico que é compatível também com o Internet Explorer 11:

```js
function produto(v){
   var res = 1;
   for(var x = 0; x < v.length; x++) res *= v[x];
   return res;
}

console.log(produto([1, 4, 7]));
```

Comment: porque você utilizou o "var res = 1", e não "0" ?

Comment: Começa em 1 porque 1 é o termo neutro da multiplicação, também chamado de elemento neutro ou elemento identidade. Ver mais em https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elemento_neutro

Comment: Se começar com zero, o resultado da multiplicação sempre será zero, independente dos números que estiverem no array

Answer (score 1):

Acho que assim já resolve o caso:

```
var result = [1, 4, 7].reduce( (a,b) => a * b );
```

Answer (score -2):

**PROBLEMA:**

Necessitamos uma função produto que receba um array de números e retorne o produto: o resultado de multiplicar todos os elementos entre si.

Por exemplo, produto([1, 4, 7]) deve retornar 28, que é 1 * 4 * 7.

---

**SOLUÇÃO:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Apesar de vir do manual de como não fazer perguntas se aplica nesse caso:[Problema de postar código como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485)