# Array Duvida JS

Tags: javascript, array

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou com dúvidas e apanhando muito para resolver esse exercício alguém poderia me dar um Help?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como faço a multiplicação de um array dentro de uma função em JS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/363601/como-fa%c3%a7o-a-multiplica%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-um-array-dentro-de-uma-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-em-js)

Comment: `[1, 4, 7].reduce((acc, i) => acc * i)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o `for` e fazer desta forma:

```js
function produto(y){
       var res = 1;
       for(var x = 0; x < y.length; x++) res *= y[x];
       return res;
    }
    
    console.log(produto([1, 4, 7]));
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo

Answer (score 1):

Na próxima vez posta sua tentativa que fica mais fácil te mostrar onde você está errando ao invés de somente darmos a resposta!

```js
function produto(array){
       //inicia resultado com o valor 1
       let resultado = 1;
       //para cada elemento do array
       array.forEach(function(elem){
           //multiplica o resultado * elemento e atribui a variavel resultado
           resultado *= elem;
       });
       //retorna o resultado
       return resultado;
    }
    
    //chama a funçao
    console.log(produto([1, 4, 7]));
```